# Why the change in pointers doesn't change the access to array?

Tags: c

Why the output is **1 7**? Since by functions "foo" and "bar" p1 wouldn't have any access to array n...

```
void foo(int *p1, int *p2)
{
    p1=p2;
    *p1=*p2+1;
}

void bar(int **p1, int **p2)
{
    p1=p2;
    *p1=*p2+1;
    **p1=**p2+2;
}

void main(void)
{
    int n[]={1,2,3};
    int m[]={4,5,6};
    int *p1=n;
    int *p2=m;

    foo(p1,p2);
    bar(&p1,&p2);
    printf("%d %d\n", *p1, *p2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes perfect sense. I won't explain `foo` because it does nothing of import -- I wouldn't be surprised if it was optimized out.

`bar` is passed `n` and `m` as parameters, then immediately overwrites `p1` (formerly `n`) with `p2` (`m`), so you have `m` and `m` as parameters. Then it increments the pointers (thus you now have `m+1` in both parameters), then it adds 2 to the first element of `m+1`. So at this point `m` looks like `4,7,6` (technically `5,7,6` if we don't ignore `foo`, but again that's irrelevant).

Outside the function you write the first number of `p1` (`n`) and `p2` (`m+1`), so you get `1` and `7`.

Comment: Actually, `foo` sets m[0] to 6.

Comment: I disagree, but you're entitled to your opinion of course. Far be it from you to actually check though before calling others wrong.

Comment: It does actually increment `m[0]` (I was wrong with the `6`, however), but that might be overwritten by `bar`. It's way too hot here to check further.

Comment: @lucky, it only changes the first value of `m` and you never display it or use it again -- irrelevant!

Comment: Ok, I got your point now. As I assumed, I should have checked `bar`. You are right - sorry, +1

Comment: thanks!! @Blindy those functions seems to overwrite **n** but by output: n is untouched while m was changed  (opposite to what those functions do)...why?

Comment: @lucky, neither `m` nor `n` are touched. If you mean `p1`, it's never changed -- your first line is `p1=p2`.

Comment: Yes, but due to your unfortunate naming scheme, you're getting confused as to which `p1` and `p2` you're talking about. It changes the parameters to `bar` (and `foo` too, it's the same first line), but not the pair in the main function.

Comment: @Blindy, Doesn't the pointers p1 p2 changed after foo and bar? so p1 is now p2...

Comment: @lucky, no. Again you never changed the pointers in `main`, you only changed the aliases passed in the parameters to `foo` and `bar`. Those are just local copies.

Answer (score 1):

```
                                      State after the line has been executed
                                      ======================================

                                      n      m      p1  p2   q1  q2
                                      -----  -----  --  ---  --  --
void foo(int *q1, int *q2)            1,2,3  4,5,6  n   m    n   m
{
    q1=q2;                            1,2,3  4,5,6  n   m    m   m
    *q1=*q2+1;                        1,2,3  5,5,6  n   m    m   m
}

                                      n      m      p1  p2   r1   r2
                                      -----  -----  --  ---  ---  ---
void bar(int **r1, int **r2)          1,2,3  5,5,6  n   m    &p1  &p2
{
    r1=r2;                            1,2,3  5,5,6  n   m    &p2  &p2
    *r1=*r2+1;                        1,2,3  5,5,6  n   m+1  &p2  &p2
    **r1=**r2+2;                      1,2,3  5,7,6  n   m+1  &p2  &p2
}

                                      n      m      p1  p2
                                      -----  -----  --  ---
void main(void)
{
    int n[]={1,2,3};                  1,2,3
    int m[]={4,5,6};                  1,2,3  4,5,6
    int *p1=n;                        1,2,3  4,5,6  n
    int *p2=m;                        1,2,3  4,5,6  n   m

    foo(p1,p2);                       1,2,3  5,5,6  n   m
    bar(&p1,&p2);                     1,2,3  5,7,6  n   m+1
    printf("%d %d\n", *p1, *p2);
}
```

Renamed some variables to avoid having to distinguishing between the various variables named `p1` and `p2`. Doing so has no effect on what happens, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for visualization!! it is very helpful.

Comment: If you tell me where the result deviates from your expectation, I can explain that bit.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce confusion, let's call the pointers in `foo()` `fp1` and `fp2`, and the pointers in `bar()` `bp1` and `bp2`... so that we can easily distinguish them from the pointers in `main()`.

In `main()`, before calling `foo()`, you've set `p1` to point at `n[0]`, and `p2` to point at `m[0]`.

When you call `foo()`, at first `fp1` and `fp2` have the values of `p1` and `p2` from `main()` and point at `n[0]` and `m[0]`... but then you set `fp1=fp2;`, so both point at `m[0]`.  The line `*fp1 = *fp2 + 1;`, then essentially does `m[0] = m[0] + 1;` so `main()`'s `m` then contains `{5,5,6}`.  `p1` and `p2` in `main()` remain unchanged (as you were working with local copies in `foo()`), so when `foo()` returns they still point at `n[0]` and `m[0]`.

When you call `bar()`, you pass pointers to `main()`'s `p1` and `p2` themselves, rather than just the values they hold.  So initially, `bp1` and `bp2` point at `p1` and `p2`, `*bp1` and `*bp2` (which *are* `main()`'s `p1` and `p2`) point at `n[0]` and `m[0]`.  The line `bp1 = bp2;` makes `bp1` also point at `main()`'s `p2`, so then both `*bp1` and `*bp2` *are* `main()`'s `p2`.  So the next line, `*bp1 = *bp2 + 1;`, is essentially `p2 = p2 + 1;` which increments `main()`'s `p2` to point at `m[1]` instead of `m[0]`.  The last line of `bar()`, `**bp1 = **bp2 + 2;`, then increments `m[1]` by `2` (since `bp1` and `bp2` are both pointers to main()'s `p2`, which points to `m[1]`).  When the function exits, `p2` in `main()` still points at `m[1]`.

So when the `printf()` occurs in `main()`, after the calls to `foo()` and `bar()`, `p1` still points at `n[0]` which still has the value `1`, and `p2` points at `m[1]` which now has the value `7`.

Comment: Does one asterisk, like in foo(int *p1, int *p2) cause for passing values that p1 p2 hold, while two asterisks like in bar(int **p1, int **p2) are causing to pass the p1 p2 themselves?

Comment: @lucky `int *` is a pointer to `int`, `int **` is a pointer to another pointer, to `int`.  In `bar()`, passing `int **` passed pointers to the pointers in `main()` -- which when dereferenced *once* could modify the pointer in `main()`, and when dereferenced *twice* could modify what the pointer in `main()` points at.